# Python pandas DataFrame operations with NaN

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

On pandas DataFrame, I'm trying to compute percent change between two features. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [100, 100, 100], 'B': [105, 110, 93], 'C': ['NaN', 102, 'NaN']})
```

I attempting to compute change between `df['A'] - df['C']`, but on the rows where we have 'NaN', use value from 'B' column.

Expecting result: `[-5, -2, 7]`
since, `df['C'].loc[0]` is NaN, first value is `100 - 105` (from 'B').
But second value is `100 -102`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simpliest is replace missing values by another column by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
#if need replace strings NaN to missing values np.nan
df['C'] = pd.to_numeric(df.C, errors='coerce')

s = df['A'] - df['C'].fillna(df.B)
print (s)
0   -5.0
1   -2.0
2    7.0
dtype: float64
```

Another idea with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and test missing values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
a = np.where(df.C.isna(), df['A'] - df['B'], df['A'] - df['C'])
print (a)
[-5. -2.  7.]
```

---

```
s = df['A'] - np.where(df.C.isna(),  df['B'], df['C'])
print (s)
0   -5.0
1   -2.0
2    7.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Really appreciate it! How do you get well with pandas? Are there any exercises we can do or just experience?

Comment: @rohan - Here are some [tutorials](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/tutorials.html#communitytutorials)